# How to dynamically access textfields in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, variables

We have a little problem accessing `TextField`-s.

We have a list of 81 (yes 81) textFields

```
private TextField textField1 = new TextField();

private TextField textField2 = new TextField();

private TextField textField3 = new TextField();

...
```

Now we want to get the text from these fields and store them in an array.

```
for loop 
  data[i] = textField???.getText();
```

How do we now incorporate the changing number `i` into the field name?

Would appreciate any help or ideas.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add all `TextField` objects to an `ArrayList` and then loop through the list calling `getText()` on each field.

Answer (score 0):

you could create an array of Textfields, so you would have:

```
private Textfield[] array_textField = new Textfield[]();

private TextField textField1 = new TextField();
array_textField[1] = textField1;

private TextField textField2 = new TextField();
array_textField[2] = textField2;

private TextField textField3 = new TextField();
array_textField[3] = textField3;
...
for loop 
data[i] = array_textField[i].getText();
```

But then you don't need the data-array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change this code as proposed by other answers you need to use Java Reflection API like so:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.Class;
int i = 0;
Class  aClass = MyObject.class
Field field = aClass.getField("someField"+i);
field.getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate over each child component, see if it's a `TextField`, and if so add it's value to the data array. This might not work depending on how your view hierarchy is structured though.

Here's a basic idea how to accomplish this:

```
    for( Component component : container.getComponents() ){
        if( component instanceof TextField ){
            // Do whatever you need 
        }
    }
```